# How can I scroll down in iftop?

Tags: networking, iftop

I installed `iftop` on my Linux Mint Rafaela Cinnamon. It frustrates me how iftop does not give an option to scroll down to see more network activity, limiting me to very little activity to be able to view. How can I see the rest of the network activity?

Comment: So, how'd it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ```
   PAUSE DISPLAY / FREEZE ORDER
      P will pause the current display.
      o will freeze the current screen order.

   This has the side effect that traffic between hosts not shown on the screen at
   the time will not be shown at all, although it will be included in the totals at 
   the bottom of the screen.

   SCROLL DISPLAY
      j and k will scroll the display of hosts.

   This feature is most useful when the display order is frozen (see above).
   ```

---

2. ```
   -t text output mode

   Use text interface without ncurses and print the output to STDOUT.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

j and k will scroll the display.